# Error: Unexpected Identifier When using an eval command

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

Ok, so I follow a youtube video on how to make an Eval command (source code: https://github.com/MenuDocs/Discord.JS-Tutorial/blob/Episode-21/commands/owner/eval.js )and in their video they can just do `eval message.author.id` and bam it works. Whereas in my bot it appears with an error in chat: `Error while evaluating: Unexpected identifier` ( https://i.stack.imgur.com/jETI9.jpg *note i use 2 'a's to keep it separate from my the bot online, reducing duplicate messages).

```
case 'evaal':
                const args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).trim().split(" ");
                const ownerID = '285198963722944514';
                if(message.author.id == ownerID) {
                    try {
                        let toEval = args.join(" ")
                        let evaluated = inspect(eval(toEval, { depth: 0 }));

                        if (!toEval) {
                            return message.channel.send("Error while evaluating: \`cannot evaluate air\`!");
                        } else {
                            let hrStart = process.hrtime()
                            let hrDiff;
                            hrDiff = process.hrtime(hrStart);
                            return message.channel.send(`*Executed in ${hrDiff[0] > 0 ? `${hrDiff[0]}s ` : ''}${hrDiff[1] / 1000000}ms.*\n\`\`\`javascript\n${evaluated}\n\`\`\``, { maxLength: 1900 })
                        }

                    } catch (e) {
                        return message.channel.send(`Error while evaluating: \`${e.message}\``)
                    }

                  } else {
                    return message.reply('You are not allowed to use this command. (Owner Only)').then(m => m.delete(5000))
                  }
        break;
```

As linked above in the imgur image, the bot responds but only with the error message. I expect it to tell me the author's id of the message (me).

Comment: Check the whole error, including its stack trace. `console.error(e)`

Comment: Here's the whole error: https://paste.menudocs.org/paste/2s3zg

Comment: What's on line 373?

Comment: `let evaluated = inspect(eval(toEval, { depth: 0 }));`
That code is the exact same as the github reference.

Comment: Try removing the second parameter from `eval()`.

Comment: still same error.

Comment: Any clue what I could do to fix?

Comment: Try declaring the evaluated code first, and then inspecting it.

Comment: `$evaal bot.on("message", async message {
message.author.id
});`
Still the same error message in chat and same error in VSCode

Comment: anything else i should attempt?

Comment: Is `inspect` defined? It should be destructured from the `util` module.

Comment: yeah it was defined, I still have no idea why it  never worked but i just ended up doing a command handler and now it works.